# Heads-up notifications in Flutter with Firebase messaging not showing

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with notification using libraries `firebase_messaging` and `flutter_local_notifications` in my Flutter application. When I try to send notification from Firebase, notification will come, but it is not showed as heads-up notification, it looks like it has lowest priority and importance.
I added channel into Manifest channel like this:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="pushnotification" />
```

and my setup of notifications in Dart:

```
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

bool isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = false;

Future<void> setupFlutterNotifications() async {
  if (isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'pushnotification',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description:
    'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  isFlutterLocalNotificationsInitialized = true;
}

void showFlutterNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      "nevim",
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          priority: Priority.max,
          importance: Importance.max,
          playSound: true,
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
 }
```

How do I need modify this code, to receive heads-up notification?